# deleting doubles in a sorted array and then puttting X in the end

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Here's the problem I've been trying to tackle for a few days.

I need to write a program that gets a sorted array. The program will put 999 where two adjacent blocks have the same value, and then put all the 999 in the end of the array. I need to do this without using another array and the program must be O(n).

example input:

`50,60,60,72,81,81,81,81,93,93`

desired output:

`50,60,72,81,93,999,999,999,999,999`

another example:

`1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6`

desired output:

`1,2,3,4,5,6,999,999,999`

my code. It's not working. For the first example the output is alright. for the second example i get 1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,-14568127 (out of array bounds)

my algorithm is i walk through the array with two indexes, i and j, if a[i]!=a[i+1] then i advance i. if they are equal, j looks for the next unique value, and puts it in a[i+1].

I'd love to hear better ideas or a code to do this. in C.

```
while((j!=size-1)&&(a[size-1]!=a[i]))
{
     if(a[i]!=a[i+1])
     {
         i++;
         j=i;
     }
     if(a[i]==a[i+1])
     {
         j=i;
         while(a[i]==a[j])
               j++;
         a[i+1]=a[j];
         i++;
         if(j!=size-1)
              j=i;
     }
}
i++
for(;i<size;i++)
      a[i]=999;
```

I've edited the code, now I do it as chen suggested. First i iterate through the array putting 999 where the doubles are, problem arises when I want to switch though. here's the code I wrote for re-sorting the array:
each time i put a 999 somewhere, count++.

It's working for the two examples I gave perfectly. Thanks everyone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void main()
{
    int *a;
    int i=0,j=0,size,count=0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    a=(int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter %d numbers\n",size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("The array recieved is :\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf(" %d ", a[i]);
    i=0;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[i+1])
        {
            j=i+1;
            while(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                a[j]=999;
                j++;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    while(count!=0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        {
            j=i;
            if(a[j]==999)
            {
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=999;
            }
        }
        count--;
    }
    printf("The new array is: \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf(" %d ",a[i]);
    free(a);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Edit your post and put your code in it so we can help you, please.

Comment: I've edited the post so you can see my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general approach that runs in **O(n)**:

**Assumption:** The input array does not contain `999` (It's fine if it does, you just have to use a different sentinel value):

- Iterate through the array once:

  - For each element, look ahead to the next one
  - If it's a duplicate to the current element, change it to `999`
  - Keep looking ahead and marking duplicates as `999` until you hit a different element.
- You want all the `999`'s at the end, so now, keep 2 separate pointers:

  - An index `X` to keep track of where the first `999` is in the array
  - Another index `num` to keep track of where we are in the swapping process
- Iterate through the array again, swap all the valid numbers with `999` using these two pointers.

This might sound confusing, so here's a pseudo animation using one of your examples:
(Using `W` as the sentinel in place of '999` for readability)

```
1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,
1,W,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,
1,W,2,3,4,W,5,6,6,
1,W,2,3,4,W,5,6,W,
1,2,W,3,4,W,5,6,W,
1,2,3,W,4,W,5,6,W,
1,2,3,4,W,W,5,6,W,
1,2,3,4,5,W,W,6,W,
1,2,3,4,5,6,W,W,W,
```

And again, but labeling the `W` with numerical suffix this time so you can see which swaps are happening:

```
1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,
1,W1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,
1,W1,2,3,4,W2,5,6,6,
1,W1,2,3,4,W2,5,6,W3,
1,2,W1,3,4,W2,5,6,W3,
1,2,3,W1,4,W2,5,6,W3,
1,2,3,4,W1,W2,5,6,W3,
1,2,3,4,5,W2,W1,6,W3,
1,2,3,4,5,6,W1,W2,W3,
```

Comment: Thanks Chen this is great stuff! But just one question, what's the algorithm for making the swaps at the end? I can put 999 on the doubles, I get that. But after I did that, whats the algorithm for the swaps?

Comment: @OriaGruber There could be a name for it, but I'm not sure; I just thought of it now when I was looking at the examples.

Comment: I don't mean the name. I meant how do I do it? I do a for loop and if a[x]=999 i just until its at the last spot? how do i know when im done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for a school exercise, and you are not working for Google and need to remove duplicates of locations in a world map, your algorithm sounds about right.

For VERY large number of potential dublicates, and also assuming the list is sorted, you could use a method based on a search for the nearest larger elemnt, and then by measuring the distance between two elements, you may find that more effecient.

Comment: I've edited the code. Please review it as you wish. And thanks for all the help I didn't realize how quick a response I'd get. Yes this is for a school exercise.

Comment: I would use `while (j < size && ... ` (and the same type of change a few lines further down)

this should be an `else`:
`if(a[i]==a[i+1])`

You set j=1 a few places more than you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to remove duplicates first, then fill the rest of the array with `999`.

Removing duplicates is O(n), and filling an array is O(n).